# In PVP are there any debuffs that cannot be dispelled as an Elemental Shaman?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

When PVPing as an Elemental Shaman are there any debuffs that another player could apply to me that I would not be able to dispel.

I know I have access to the following spells:

- [Cleanse Spirit] - Removes all Curse effects from a friendly target.
- [Glyph of Shamanistic Range] - Activating your Shamanistic Rage ability also cleanses you of all dispellable harmful Magic effects.
- [Cure Toxins] - Cures 1 poison effect and 1 disease effect on a friendly target.

Comment: Probably should have made it specific to elemental shammy if that was all you were going to post about. The question yells broad applys to all classes, but the rest seems to focus entirely on a particular build of Shaman.

Comment: @Timelord64, I have restructured the question to be specific, though I feel the answer should also maintain the more general details so that other classes can find this useful as well, what do you think?

Comment: If you generalise this to all classes, this could be seen as too broad, just like the previous question that asked specificaly about elemental shammys. If you can answer it all yourself, sure. If not, I would leave it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an Elemental Shaman with the spells mentioned you will be able dispell as follows:

- Any Curse debuff with Cleanse Spirit
- Any Magic debuff with Glyph of Shamanistic Rage
- Any Disease debuff with Cure Toxins
- Any Poison debuff with Cure Toxins

This leaves only physical effects that cannot be dispelled, which actually cannot be dispelled by anyone.

To expand more generally on this, all player initiated debuffs are dispellable with the exception of physical debuffs and with some limitations I will detail below:

- All dispels are limited to dispelling a subset of the types of debuffs

  - Poison - e.g. [Deadly Poison](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/wiki/Deadly_Poison) - dispellable by Paladin, Druid, Shaman
  - Disease - e.g. [Frost Fever](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/wiki/Frost_Fever) - dispellable by Paladin, Shaman, Priest
  - Magic - e.g. [Misery](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/wiki/Misery) - dispellable by Priest, Warlock, Paladin, Shaman (with Glyph)
  - Curse - e.g. [Curse of the Elements](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/wiki/Curse_of_the_Elements) - dispellable by Mage, Druid, Shaman
  - Physical - e.g. [Demoralizing Shout](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/wiki/Demoralizing_Shout) - these are not dispellable
- Some debuffs will prevent you from casting any spells which would limit your ability to dispell yourself, e.g. [Hammer of Justice]. However, there are some abilities that allow you to break out of stuns, spells like [Ice Block] and also the [PVP trinkets](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/wiki/Insignia_of_the_Alliance_(Druid)) are an example of this.

If you are unsure of what school a debuff falls into you can either mouse over it in game and read the tooltip or look it up on wowhead or wow wiki.

Finally if you do use addons then something like [Decursive](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAAahUKEwjyneadl9THAhWJmYgKHSvkDxs&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.curse.com%2Faddons%2Fwow%2Fdecursive&ei=37vkVbKyKImzogSryL_YAQ&usg=AFQjCNHKpiZIRi2sNAQHc-V-Pbzzzh0O3g&sig2=8pEKvMhkucqi8-Ubn0GNug) will actually change your UI in a way that will show you debuffs that you are able to dispell, a lot of unit/raid frame replacements will also provide this same functionality, [ElvUI](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAAahUKEwjBwJ_Ll9THAhWEKYgKHUpzAHM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tukui.org%2Fdl.php&ei=PrzkVcGpO4TToATK5oGYBw&usg=AFQjCNE_wHG31PQdVnOSdMFigrvxiXy_rw&sig2=HAVyNMfevRpdHgVEzjrsvw) is an example of this.

All of this information was sourced from [WowWiki](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/wiki/Debuff)